# Passing class to constructor in typescript results in error

Tags: typescript

I have some nested services I'm trying to create in Typescript, and I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax.

Here is the basic example:

```
class Service {
    constructor() { }
}

class AnotherService {
    constructor(private service: Service) { }
}

class yetAnotherService {
    constructor(private service: AnotherService) {  }
}

let myService = new yetAnotherService(AnotherService);
```

The last line errors with

```
Argument of type 'typeof AnotherService' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnotherService'.
  Property 'service' is missing in type 'typeof AnotherService'.
```

This could be a duplicate question but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation is wrong. The following

```
constructor(private service: AnotherService) {  }
```

Should be

```
constructor(private service: typeof AnotherService) {  }
```

## More

You want a class type not an instance.

Comment: But now I cannot call any methods on the service from within the class?